# Large Hover Menu/Navigation Menu - Categorically Bad UX?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, menu, hover, click

Due to feedback from a handful of customers that did not understand what our menu icons meant, a hamburger icon was removed from our navigation menu, this hamburger icon was used to expand the navigation menu.

[image]

In place of the hamburger icon action, a hover event now expands the navigation menu:
[image]

Hover does not imply intent:

- It is frustrating to hover over something and have it do something
  not intended.
- Especially frustrating, if the hover causes a sweeping full screen
  animation that darkens the entire website with an opaque black and
  expands a large menu.
- What if the user's intent was to click a menu icon that has become
  familiar?

Hovering over an icon, causing a tooltip to display is the standard solution for explaining what an icon is/does, yes?

Is it not fair and reasonable non-subjective to say that?:

This hovering menu nav is, unfortunately, just bad UI/UX. Hovering menus are an observable, industry standard bad practice, particularly as a solution to the problem we are trying to solve for our customers: describing what our menu icons mean.

- [4 reasons why hover menus are problematic](https://medium.com/simple-human/why-hover-menus-are-problematic-b21d6c7de91c)
- [Navigation drop-downs. Should they be hover or click?](https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/navigation-drop-downs-should-they-be-hover-or-click/)
- [Why Hover Menus Do Users More Harm Than Good](https://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-hover-menus-do-users-more-harm-than-good/)

Comment: Could you add the version with the hamburger icon too? Maybe the problem wasn’t the hamburger icon itself but how it was presented in relation to the other icon.

Comment: The age old battle between ease of use and ease of discovery. I think.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue was "did not understand what our menu icons meant" would tool-tip help? Hamburgers are standard these days and removing it completely might cause users search for it.

I too agree on the hover over actions becoming frustrating. I was thinking adding back a hamburger with tool-tip and on click of hamburger menu can expand the menu, especially if there are sub-menus hidden.

Cheers,
Arty

Answer (score 1):

You have some options here.

1. Show the labels all the time.
2. Improve the icons. The icons shown are very generic and could mean anything. BOM appears to be using the numbered list icon I can see when I type this.
3. Change hover behaviour to show tooltips.

I agree that hover to expand is not a great experience. It can especially be problematic on touch interfaces.